# Matplotlib plot window is not closing with command-w

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am using ipython3 on my mac, with the following version

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12)
```

and `matplotlib` version 2.0.0

I changed the backend from `macosx` to `qt5agg` in my `matplotlibrc` file.
Now, when I hit `cmd-w` to close a window, this doesn't work anymore.
Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib and anaconda python under MacOS don't work that well together because Matplotlib requires a Framework build of python to be able to call the `macosx` backend.
I see many answers around recommending changing the backend, but that is dealing with the symptoms, and not with the root of the problem.

Anaconda now ships with a Framework build binary of python as well. Instead of *python3*, it is called **pythonw3**.

To use matplotlib from Ipython, and to make sure that everything works fine with the native `macosx` backend, change your ipython interpreter from:

```
$HOME/anaconda3/bin/ipython3
```

to

```
$HOME/anaconda3/bin/pythonw3 -m IPython -i
```

Closing windows with Cmd+w should now work alright.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be caused by anaconda, but by `qt5agg` (or the underlying Qt5). I am using a framework build of python, not provided by anaconda, and I also cannot close my plots with `cmd-w`. `cmd-q` works fine. `cmd-w` worked fine with either `tkagg` or `macosx` backends.