# Is there a way to close a plot created with matplotlib from terminal (without having to close the window with mouse)

Tags: python, matplotlib, command-line, terminal

Is there a way to close a plot created with matplotlib from a command in terminal (without having to close the window with mouse)?

I'm using `zsh` on macos 10.15.7

Let's say I have a file `plot1.py` with following content:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

from the command line, when I execute `python plot1.py` this opens a window displaying the plot. What I would like to do is close this window from the terminal with a keyboard command. I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> without success and I have to close the window with the mouse by clicking on the close button

Note: I am not using anaconda (as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273402/matplotlib-plot-window-is-not-closing-with-command-w)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `block` argument of the `plt.show` method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(1)
input()
plt.close()
```

With the above code, you can close the window whenever you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the terminal.

---

You also can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, making sure that the `matplotlib` window is above the terminal window. Of course, that is a windows hot key rather than a terminal shortcut...

Comment: Many thanks @AnnZen! that works! Do you have a reference by any case?

Comment: @ecjb Reference?

Comment: I mean a source / website where you got the information?

Comment: @ecjb Check this out https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show

Answer (score 0):

late answer but noone mentioned simple solution :
removing plt.show() from the code removes the problem

Comment: This does not answer the question. Removing `ply.show()` will make it so the plot never appears. Per the question it is clear OP wants to know how to close the window, not how to prevent the window from opening in the first place.